# Center of a topological group is closed?

Tags: topological-groups

Is it true that the center $Z$ of a topological group $G$ is closed?(maybe we need the space to be Hausdorff or something like that...) I was thinking I can just show it is opened. So if I pick $x\in Z$ then I need to find an open $U \ni x$ such that $U\subset Z$. But I am not sure how to show it.

Comment: What's the centre of $O(3)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The centre of $G$ is the intersection of the centralisers of its elements.
The centralizers are closed, so the centre is too.

In more detail
$$Z(G)=\bigcap_{g\in C}C_G(g)$$
where
$$C_G(g)=\{h\in G:ghg^{-1}h^{-1}=e\}$$
is closed in $G$.

Comment: +1. And to fill in a step for the OP: to see that $C_G(g)$ is closed, show that the map $$\mu_g:h\mapsto ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$$ is continuous and therefore $C_G(g)=\mu_g^{-1}(\{e\})$ is the continuous preimage of a closed set.

Comment: thanks to both!